# Code coverage only 28%, what to do to get it to 100%

Tags: unit-test

I am stuck at 28% code coverage. What am I supposed to do to get it to 100%?

This is my test class

```
@isTest 

public class vf_CommunityPlanGoalPSetting_Test 
{

    @testSetup static void test_DataSetup() 
    {

        Id acctRTypeId = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE sObjectType='Account' AND Name='FIGS Federation Account' LIMIT 1].ID;
        Id contactRTypeId = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE sObjectType='Contact' AND Name='Contact' LIMIT 1].ID;

        List<Account> acctList = new List<Account>();
        List<Contact> contactList = new List<Contact>();

        Account a1 = new Account(Name='AccountTest1',RecordTypeId=acctRTypeId); 
        Account a2 = new Account(Name='AccountTest2',RecordTypeId=acctRTypeId);  
        Account a3 = new Account(Name='AccountTest3',RecordTypeId=acctRTypeId);    
        acctList.add(a1);
        acctList.add(a2);
        acctList.add(a3);
        insert acctList;

        Contact c1 = new Contact(FirstName='firstName',LastName='ContactTest1',RecordTypeId=contactRTypeId,Constituent_Code__c='Donor',AccountId=acctList[0].id);
        Contact c2 = new Contact(FirstName='firstName',LastName='ContactTest2',RecordTypeId=contactRTypeId,Constituent_Code__c='Donor',AccountId=acctList[1].id); 
        Contact c3 = new Contact(FirstName='firstName',LastName='ContactTest3',RecordTypeId=contactRTypeId,Constituent_Code__c='Donor',AccountId=acctList[2].id);  
        contactList.add(c1);
        contactList.add(c2);
        contactList.add(c3);
        insert contactList;

        Community_Yearly_Plan__c cyp1 = new Community_Yearly_Plan__c(Federation__c = acctList[0].id);
        Community_Yearly_Plan__c cyp2 = new Community_Yearly_Plan__c(Federation__c = acctList[1].id);
        insert cyp1;
        insert cyp2;

        Community_Plan_Goal_Setting__c cpgs1 = new Community_Plan_Goal_Setting__c(year__c='2015',Community_Plan__c=cyp1.Id);
        Community_Plan_Goal_Setting__c cpgs2 = new Community_Plan_Goal_Setting__c(year__c='2016',Community_Plan__c=cyp2.id);        
        insert cpgs1;
        insert cpgs2;  

    }

    static testMethod void unitTest () 
    {
        Id acctRTypeId = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE sObjectType='Account' AND Name='FIGS Federation Account' LIMIT 1].ID;
        Account a1 = new Account(Name='AccountTest1',RecordTypeId=acctRTypeId); 
        insert a1;

        Test.setCurrentPageReference(new PageReference('Page.vf_CommunityPlanGoalPSetting'));
        vf_CommunityPlanGoalPSetting_Cntrlr controller = new vf_CommunityPlanGoalPSetting_Cntrlr(new ApexPages.StandardController(a1));

        Test.StartTest();


        Test.StopTest();

    }
}
```

This is my controller

```
public class vf_CommunityPlanGoalPSetting_Cntrlr {



    public List<Community_Plan_Goal_Setting__c> listGoalsCurrYear {get;set;}
    public List<Community_Plan_Goal_Setting__c> listGoalsPrevYears {get;set;}
    public String ft { get; set; }
    public String ccp { get; set; }
    public String fa { get; set; }
    public String fd { get; set; }
    public String ga { get; set; }
    public String gac { get; set; }    
    public String newRow {get;set;}
    public Boolean showMsg {get;set;}

    public String currentYear = String.valueOf(System.Today().year()) ; 
    public String parentID;


    //Variable to hold add records to be deleted
    public List<Community_Plan_Goal_Setting__c> deleteList = new List<Community_Plan_Goal_Setting__c>();

    public vf_CommunityPlanGoalPSetting_Cntrlr(ApexPages.StandardController controller) 
    {    
        //Show warning that one must click on save/update button to save changes
        showMsg = False;
        ApexPages.Message myMsgShowSaveInfo = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO,'');
        ApexPages.addMessage(myMsgShowSaveInfo);
        listGoalsCurrYear = new Community_Plan_Goal_Setting__c[]{};
            listGoalsPrevYears = new Community_Plan_Goal_Setting__c[]{};    
                parentID = controller.getID();
        // get all records for all years        
        for(Community_Plan_Goal_Setting__c cpgs : [ SELECT id,Year__c,Funding_Type__c,Funding_Amount__c,Funding_Description__c,Funding_Comments__c,
                                                   Core_Current_Participation__c,
                                                   Goal_Amount__c,Goal_Amount_Comments__c,Community_Plan__c,Name,EditableOrReadOnly__c,Funding_Type_Description__c 
                                                   FROM Community_Plan_Goal_Setting__c
                                                   WHERE Community_Plan__r.id = :parentID
                                                   ORDER BY Year__c]){
                                                       // add all records to currYear section (top) which is editable

                                                       if(cpgs.Year__c == currentYear) // Get current years goals
                                                       { 
                                                           listGoalsCurrYear.add(cpgs);
                                                       }
                                                       else if (Integer.valueOf(cpgs.Year__c) == Integer.valueOf(currentYear)-1) // Only show last years goals not older
                                                       {
                                                           listGoalsPrevYears.add(cpgs);
                                                       }

                                                   }

        // Add how ever many previous years rows to the current year
        if (!listGoalsPrevYears.isEmpty())
        {
            for (Community_Plan_Goal_Setting__c cpgsnew : listGoalsPrevYears)
            {
                AddRowForPreviousYearsData(cpgsnew.Funding_Type__c,cpgsnew.Core_Current_Participation__c,cpgsnew.Funding_Description__c,cpgsnew.Funding_Comments__c, cpgsnew.Funding_Type_Description__c);                    

            }
        }

    }

    public Void AddRowForPreviousYearsData(String fundingType, String  coreCurrentParticipation, String fundingDescription, String fundingComments, String description)
    {
        // Create new record for each row of previous years data
        Community_Plan_Goal_Setting__c cpgs = new Community_Plan_Goal_Setting__c(year__c = String.valueOf(System.Today().year()), Community_Plan__c = parentID,Funding_Type__c=fundingType,Core_Current_Participation__c=coreCurrentParticipation,Funding_Description__c=fundingDescription,Funding_Comments__c=fundingComments,Funding_Type_Description__c=description);

        //This next line allowes fields to be displayed in edit mode for new records
        if( cpgs.year__c == String.valueOf(System.Today().year()) ) newRow = 'nr';        

        listGoalsCurrYear.add(cpgs);

        //        return null;
    }

    public pageReference AddRow()
    {
        // Create new record for each row
        Community_Plan_Goal_Setting__c cpgs = new Community_Plan_Goal_Setting__c(year__c = String.valueOf(System.Today().year()), Community_Plan__c = parentID);

        //This next line allows fields to be displayed in edit mode for new records
        if( cpgs.year__c == String.valueOf(System.Today().year()) ) newRow = 'nr';        

        listGoalsCurrYear.add(cpgs);

        return null;
    }

    public pageReference SaveRecords()
    {
        ApexPages.Message myMsgSuccess = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO,'Your changes were saved.');  
        showMsg = True;
        //Save the list of records
        upsert listGoalsCurrYear;   

        // Delete records if necessary
        if(deleteList.size()>0 && deleteList <> NULL)
        {
            delete deleteList;
        }

        // Show feedback
        ApexPages.addMessage(myMsgSuccess);

        return null;    
    }

    //Remove a record from the table.
    public pageReference removeRecord(){
        Integer indexVal = Integer.valueof(system.currentpagereference().getparameters().get('index'));

        //If existing then add it to the list to delete from the database
        if(listGoalsCurrYear[indexVal - 1].Id != null) deleteList.add(listGoalsCurrYear[indexVal - 1]);

        //Remove row from the table    
        listGoalsCurrYear.remove(indexVal - 1);   

        return null;
    }    

}
```

This is my VF page

```
<apex:page standardController="Community_Yearly_Plan__c" extensions="vf_CommunityPlanGoalPSetting_Cntrlr" cache="false">

    <style>
        <!-- This style is to make the Pagereference Warning red background and white letters -->    
        .warningM2 {
        background-color: #DC441E; // Make the Warning message red background
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        color: #000;
        padding: 6px 8px 6px 6px;
        margin: 4px 20px;
        color: white;
        }
        .message .messageText {
        margin-left: 8px;
        color: white; // Make font color white
        }
        .infoM3 {
        background-color: #46A86A; // Make the Save message green background
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        color: #000;
        padding: 6px 8px 6px 6px;
        margin: 4px 20px;
        color: white;
        }
    </style>   

    <apex:form >

        <c:PageBlockTableEnhancerADV id="pbeADV" targetPbTableIds="pbtCon" enableExport="false" paginate="true" defaultPageSize="5" pageSizeOptions="1,2,3,5,10,20"/>        
        <apex:pageblock >
            <apex:outputText><b>Prior Years</b></apex:outputText>
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" id="pbsCon" >
                <apex:outputPanel id="panelCon2">
                    <c:PageBlockTableEnhancerADV id="pbeADV" targetPbTableIds="pbtCon2" enableExport="false" paginate="true" defaultPageSize="5" pageSizeOptions="1,2,3,5,10,20"/>                            
                    <div id="loading-curtain-div"/>

                    <apex:pageBlockTable id="pbtCon2" value="{!listGoalsPrevYears}" var="cpgs2">

                        <apex:column value="{!cpgs2.Year__c}" />                        
                        <apex:column >
                            <apex:facet name="header">Funding Type</apex:facet>                            
                            <apex:outputField value="{!cpgs2.Funding_Type__c}" rendered="{!IF(cpgs2.EditableOrReadOnly__c!='True','True','False')}" />                            

                        </apex:column>   
                        <apex:column >
                            <apex:facet name="header">Description</apex:facet>                                                         
                            <apex:outputField id="ccp" value="{!cpgs2.Core_Current_Participation__c}" rendered="{!IF(cpgs2.Funding_Type__c!='Elective' && cpgs2.Funding_Type__c!='Other','True','False')}" />
                            <apex:outputField id="ftd" value="{!cpgs2.Funding_Type_Description__c}" rendered="{!IF(cpgs2.Funding_Type__c='Elective' || cpgs2.Funding_Type__c='Other','True','False')}" />                            
                        </apex:column>   
                        <!--                        <apex:column >
<apex:facet name="header">Funding Description</apex:facet>                                                                                     
<apex:outputField value="{!cpgs2.Funding_Description__c}" rendered="{!IF(cpgs2.EditableOrReadOnly__c!='True','True','False')}" />
</apex:column>   
-->                        <apex:column >
                        <apex:facet name="header">Goal Amount</apex:facet>                                                                                     
                        <apex:outputField value="{!cpgs2.Goal_Amount__c}" rendered="{!IF(cpgs2.EditableOrReadOnly__c!='True','True','False')}" />
                        </apex:column>   
                        <apex:column >
                            <apex:facet name="header">Goal Amount Comments</apex:facet>                                                        
                            <apex:outputField value="{!cpgs2.Goal_Amount_Comments__c}" rendered="{!IF(cpgs2.EditableOrReadOnly__c!='True','True','False')}" />
                        </apex:column>   
                        <apex:column >
                            <apex:facet name="header">Funding Amount</apex:facet>                                                                                     
                            <apex:outputField value="{!cpgs2.Funding_Amount__c}" rendered="{!IF(cpgs2.EditableOrReadOnly__c!='True','True','False')}" />                            
                        </apex:column>   
                    </apex:pageBlockTable>

                </apex:outputPanel>                

                <apex:outputPanel id="panelCon">
                    <div id="loading-curtain-div"/>
                    <apex:outputText ><b>Planning Years</b></apex:outputText>                    
                    <apex:pageBlockTable id="pbtCon" value="{!listGoalsCurrYear}" var="cpgs">
                        <apex:variable value="{!0}" var="cnt"/>   
                        <apex:column headervalue="Action">
                            <apex:commandlink value="Remove" onclick="return validateFunction();" action="{!removeRecord}" immediate="true">
                                <!-- Pass the row number to the controller so that we know which row to remove -->
                                <apex:param name="index" value="{!cnt}"/>
                            </apex:commandlink> 
                            <apex:variable var="cnt" value="{!cnt+1}"/>  
                        </apex:column>  

                        <!--                        <apex:column value="{!cpgs.Year__c}" />                        
-->                        
                        <apex:column >
                            <apex:facet name="header">Year</apex:facet>                             
                            <apex:inputField id="hdr" value="{!cpgs.Year__c}" rendered="True" />
                        </apex:column>   
                        <apex:column >
                            <apex:facet name="header">Funding Type</apex:facet>                             
                            <apex:inputField id="ft" value="{!cpgs.Funding_Type__c}" rendered="True" />
                        </apex:column>   
                        <apex:column >
                            <apex:facet name="header">Description</apex:facet>                                                         
                            <apex:inputField id="ccp" value="{!cpgs.Core_Current_Participation__c}" rendered="{!IF(cpgs.Funding_Type__c!='Elective' && cpgs.Funding_Type__c!='Other','True','False')}" />
                            <apex:inputField id="ftd" value="{!cpgs.Funding_Type_Description__c}" rendered="{!IF(cpgs.Funding_Type__c='Elective' || cpgs.Funding_Type__c='Other','True','False')}" />                            

                        </apex:column>   
                        <!--                        <apex:column >
<apex:facet name="header">Funding Description</apex:facet>                                                         
<apex:inputField id="fd" value="{!cpgs.Funding_Description__c}" rendered="True" />
</apex:column>   
-->
                        <apex:column >
                            <apex:facet name="header">Goal Amount</apex:facet>                                                         
                            <apex:inputField id="ga" value="{!cpgs.Goal_Amount__c}" rendered="True" />
                        </apex:column>   
                        <apex:column >
                            <apex:facet name="header">Goal Amount Comments</apex:facet>                            
                            <apex:inputField id="gac" value="{!cpgs.Goal_Amount_Comments__c}" rendered="True" />
                        </apex:column>   
                        <apex:column >
                            <apex:facet name="header">Funding Amount</apex:facet>                                                         
                            <apex:inputField id="fa" value="{!cpgs.Funding_Amount__c}" rendered="True"  />
                        </apex:column>   

                    </apex:pageBlockTable>

                    <apex:commandButton style="align:center;" action="{!AddRow}" value="Add Funding/Goal" reRender="pbsCon" />
                    <apex:commandButton style="align:center;" action="{!SaveRecords}" value="Save/Update" reRender="pbsCon" />                    

                    <apex:pageMessage summary="PLEASE NOTE: Any changes including adding or deleting rows only go into effect when the 'Save/Update' button is clicked. Otherwise changes are lost when one leaves or refreshes the page." severity="warning" strength="3" />

                    <apex:pageMessages rendered="{!showMsg}" />


                </apex:outputPanel>

            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
    <script>    

    function validateFunction()
    {

        var r = confirm('Are you sure you want to remove this row?');
        if (r == true) 
        {
            return true
        } else 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }


    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When writing tests for a Visualforce page, you are really only testing the page's Apex controller. So you have to call each controller public method and assert the results from your test. At the moment you are only invoking the controller's constructor but none of its methods.

If when you are invoking the methods you are still not getting good coverage, use the Developer Console's [Checking Code Coverage](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_dev_console_tests_coverage.htm&type=0) feature to identify the blocks of code that are not covered so you can identify how to vary the input data to get more coverage.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. I added my methods and now I have a bunch more questions on this test. Should I make each error a new question or continue this thread?

Comment: FYI, right now I am at 48%

Comment: @ApexN-u-b Having to add test code to up the coverage is part of the normal development process. Examine the uncovered blocks and think about what variations of the data will achieve the coverage and more importantly what the resulting outcome will be so you can add the assertions that are the core point of having tests. Best usually to have multiple test methods that test different combinations of data.